# Blacklist a role in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

after trying so many thing I came up with the idea to ask you intelligent people out there! I want to blacklist 3 roles for a single command. But everything I tried failed.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
member = ctx.message.author
roleA = get(member.guild.roles, name="Rote Birdys")
roleB = get(member.guild.roles, name="Grüne Birdys")
roleC = get(member.guild.roles, name="Blaue Birdys")

if commands.has_any_role(roleA, roleB, roleC):
    return
```

Nothing worked, I tried some more things but they didn't work either. May I'm really stupid but I need to finish this projekt in a few weeks and I'm stuck here.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: So you want it to be so that if the person calling the command has any of those 3 roles it won't run?

Comment: Yeahm if the user has only one of these roles the command should not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the `has_any_role` check but backwards. I also created a new error like `MissingAnyRole`:

```
from discord.ext.commands import check, CheckFailure
import discord.utils

class HasForbiddenRole(CheckFailure):
    def __init__(self, forbidden_roles):
        self.forbidden_roles = forbidden_roles

        forbidden= ["'{}'".format(role) for role in forbidden_roles]

        if len(missing) > 2:
            fmt = '{}, or {}'.format(", ".join(forbidden[:-1]), forbidden[-1])
        else:
            fmt = ' or '.join(forbidden)

        message = "You have at least one of the forbidden roles: {}".format(fmt)
        super().__init__(message)

def lacks_every_role(*items):
    def predicate(ctx):
        if not isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.abc.GuildChannel):
            raise NoPrivateMessage()

        getter = functools.partial(discord.utils.get, ctx.author.roles)
        if not any(getter(id=item) is not None if isinstance(item, int) else getter(name=item) is not None for item in items):
            return True
        raise HasForbiddenRole(items)

    return check(predicate)
```

Usage would be like any of the other checks:

```
@lacks_every_role("Rote Birdys", "Grüne Birdys", "Blaue Birdys")  # You could also use role ids
@bot.command()
async def comm(ctx):
    ...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! But somehow, when I try to add this as a cog is says that @lack_every_role is not defined.

Comment: Okay my main Problem now is, when I put everything in the main file it says that the variable `message` is undifened

Comment: The only `message` I use is defined in the like `message = ...`

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad. It worked. Thank you so much! The project is working well and eveyone it happy. Thanks a lot. :D